# Socket java transfer a bit string to the server. StringBuilder Transfer

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a task. By socket, pass the variable output.

```
            String hex = "1040014116";
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
            String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
             }
             System.out.println(output);
```

output has the form "0x10.."

There is a web server he needs to transfer this data and in return receive others.

```
        int serverPort = 2003; 
        String address = "xx.xx.xx.xx"; 


        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); 
            System.out.println(" IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort); 
            System.out.println("Socket ready");


            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();


            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = null;

            System.out.println("Введите данные и нажмите 'Ввод'");
            System.out.println();

            while (true) {
                line = reader.readLine(); 
                System.out.println("Отправка на сервер");
                out.writeUTF(line);// отправка текста
                System.out.println("Отправка: : " + line);
                out.flush(); // конец передачи
                line = in.readUTF(); // возврат текста от сервера
                System.out.println("Сервер: : " + line);
                System.out.println("Введите новую строку");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

How to pass a bit string and get a bit string from the server in response.

Comment: Maybe also add the `java` tag?

Answer (score 0):

U need to code on both client and server side

SERVER code

```
ServerSocket sskt=new ServerSocket(port);
Socket =sskt.accept()
InputStream is=skt.getInputStream();
OutputStream os=skt.getOutputStream();
```

ClIENT code

```
Socket skt=new Socket(server_ip,port);
```

Use same inputstream and outputstream to read and write once the connection has been established

Hope this helps